# javascript to connect to local RestfulApi fail

Tags: php, jquery, html

So i'm try to create an social web. So in my html i have this scrip

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajax({

                    type: "GET",
                    url: "api/posts",
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    data: '',
                    success: function(r) {
                            var posts = JSON.parse(r)
                            $.each(posts, function(index) {
                                    $('.timelineposts').html(
                                            $('.timelineposts').html() + '<blockquote><p>'+posts[index].PostBody+'</p><footer>Posted by '+posts[index].PostedBy+' on '+posts[index].PostDate+'<button class="btn btn-default" type="button" style="color:#eb3b60;background-image:url(&quot;none&quot;);background-color:transparent;"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart" data-aos="flip-right"></i><span> '+posts[index].Likes+' Likes</span></button><button class="btn btn-default comment" type="button" style="color:#eb3b60;background-image:url(&quot;none&quot;);background-color:transparent;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-flash" style="color:#f9d616;"></i><span style="color:#f9d616;"> Comments</span></button></footer></blockquote>'
                                    )
                            })
                    },
                    error: function(r) {
                            console.log(r)
                    }

            });
    });
</script>
```

This script in order to connect to RESTFul API in my local folder api then get all post in timeline. But when i run index.html it does not show any post in timeline. What wrong with this?

This is my console.log(r):

```
This site appears to use a scroll-linked positioning effect. This may not work well with asynchronous panning; see https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Mozilla/Performance/ScrollLinkedEffects for further details and to join the discussion on related tools and features!  edit

TypeError: this._tabPool is null  tab.js:1419:5

TypeError: this._tabPool is null tab.js:1419:5

TypeError: this._tabPool is null  tab.js:1419:5

Use of Mutation Events is deprecated. Use MutationObserver instead.  aos.js:1:2238

SyntaxError: JSON.parse: bad control character in string literal at line 1 column 357 of the JSON data  index.html:132:45
```

This is my index.php in api folder:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "GET") {

    if ($_GET['url'] == "auth") {

    } else if ($_GET['url'] == "users") {

    } else if ($_GET['url'] == "posts") {

            $token = $_COOKIE['SNID'];

            $userid = $db->query('SELECT user_id FROM login_tokens WHERE token=:token', array(':token'=>sha1($token)))[0]['user_id'];

            $followingposts = $db->query('SELECT posts.id, posts.body, posts.posted_at, posts.likes, users.`username` FROM users, posts, followers
            WHERE posts.user_id = followers.user_id
            AND users.id = posts.user_id
            AND follower_id = :userid
            ORDER BY posts.likes DESC;', array(':userid'=>$userid));
            $response = "[";
            foreach($followingposts as $post) {

                    $response .= "{";
                            $response .= '"PostId": '.$post['id'].',';
                            $response .= '"PostBody": "'.$post['body'].'",';
                            $response .= '"PostedBy": "'.$post['username'].'",';
                            $response .= '"PostDate": "'.$post['posted_at'].'",';
                            $response .= '"Likes": '.$post['likes'].'';
                    $response .= "},";


            }
            $response = substr($response, 0, strlen($response)-1);
            $response .= "]";

            http_response_code(200);
            echo $response;

    }
```

For more information : When i try to run : localhost/api/posts i got this error :

```
Notice: Undefined index: SNID in /opt/lampp/htdocs/api/index.php on line 15

Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /opt/lampp/htdocs/api/index.php on line 17
```

]

line 15 is $_COOKIE['SNID']
Line 17 is userid = ...

Cookie SNID is some thing in login php file that the guy HowCode create cookies name SNID to store login info of users.
And in fact that i'm follow this guide : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lj-6KIg6VSI

Comment: Any console or network errors? `console.log(r)`? Contents of your /api/post file? Response from the file?

Comment: `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: bad control character in string....` suggests json is not being returned from `api/posts`

Comment: The first thing that jumps out at me is that the content type is being set to json, but the data you give it is `''` which is not valid json.  You might try changing that to `'{}'`

Comment: Could you please post the JSON

Comment: Already push it :( Anyone... Thanks so much